# program not exiting upon GUI creation

Tags: java, swing

For testing purposes I have created a GUI in my ClientGUI class. The program never seems to exit and hangs.I call my create function in main to see how the gui looks and after this the program should terminate but instead it hangs.Please explain to me why this is happening.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.net.*;

public class ClientGUI extends JFrame{

// creates username textfield
private JLabel username = new JLabel("Username ");
private JTextField textUsername = new JTextField(10);

//creates password textfield
private JLabel password = new JLabel("Password ");
private JPasswordField passText = new JPasswordField(10);

// adding two buttons
private JButton Login = new JButton("Login");
private JButton Create = new JButton("Create");

private JPanel error;
private JFrame my_error;
private JLabel errormsg = new JLabel("Error Try Again");
private JButton cancel_me = new JButton("OK");
private String option;
private String usr_name;
private char [] ident;
private String pass;
private String passme;
public volatile boolean []go = new boolean[1];

// constructor
ClientGUI(){

    super("GossApp"); //title of jframe

       }

public void CreatGui(){

    JPanel myPanel = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout()); // creates a panel of type gridbaglayout
    GridBagConstraints GridC = new GridBagConstraints();// constraints for layout
    GridC.insets = new Insets(0,10,0,10); // spacing

    // position 0,0 is corner
    GridC.gridx = 0;
    GridC.gridy = 0;
    myPanel.add(username, GridC); // adding to panel

    // position 0,1 adding user text field below username
    GridC.gridy = 1;
    myPanel.add(textUsername, GridC);

    // position 0, 2 adding password name below user
    GridC.gridx = 0;
    GridC.gridy = 2;
    myPanel.add(password, GridC);

    //position 0,3 adding password text field below password
    GridC.gridy = 3;
    myPanel.add(passText, GridC);

    // adding login button to panel next to password text
    GridC.gridx = 1;
    GridC.gridy = 3;
    myPanel.add(Login, GridC);

    Login.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            /*
            String my_name = textUsername.getText();
            char [] my_password = passText.getPassword();
            String my_stringword = new String(my_password);
            */
            option ="log";
            whileLog(option);
        }
    });

    // adding create button gui next to user text field
    GridC.gridx = 1;
    GridC.gridy = 1;
    myPanel.add(Create,GridC);

    Create.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            option= "create";
            whileLog(option);
        }
    });

    add(myPanel); //adds gui to jframe
    setSize(270,170); // creates dimensions of frame
    setLocationRelativeTo(null); // center gui
    setVisible(true); // I can see!

    my_error = new JFrame("Error");
    error = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());
    GridC.gridx= 1;
    GridC.gridy = 1;

    error.add(cancel_me,GridC);
    cancel_me.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            my_error.setVisible(false);
        }
    });

    GridC.gridy = 2;
    error.add(errormsg,GridC);
    my_error.add(error);
    my_error.pack();
    my_error.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
    my_error.setVisible(false);

}



public class clientserver{

public static void main(String[]args) {

    ClientGUI my_gui = new ClientGUI();
    my_gui.CreatGui();
}
}
```

Comment: I suspect that `whileLog` is blocking the EDT - See [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for the "why" and [Worker Threads and SwingWorker](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) for a possible "how"

Comment: probably because the `my_error` `JFrame` wll allways just go invisible instead of beeing destroyed, this will keep the `JVM` running. You also need to set `JFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE)` in order for your `JFrame` to properly close, otherwise closing it will make is dispose and not exit really

Comment: I tried commenting out whilelog and got the same result

Comment: @SomeJavaGuy YOU ARE A GENIUS!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to set

```
setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
```

For your `ClientGui`, otherwise the default kicks in, which makes it not really close. The default keeps the JVM running as the `JFrame` hasn´t been destroyed properly.

an additional small paragraph from the [methods documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JFrame.html#setDefaultCloseOperation(int)), which shows what the default is.

> [...]
>
> HIDE_ON_CLOSE (defined in WindowConstants): Automatically hide the frame after invoking any registered WindowListener objects.
>
> [...]
>
> EXIT_ON_CLOSE (defined in JFrame): Exit the application using the System exit method. Use this only in applications.
>
> [...]
>
> The value is set to HIDE_ON_CLOSE by default. Changes to the value of this property cause the firing of a property change event, with property name "defaultCloseOperation".
>
> [...]